# Printing a 2D Array using pointers pointing to pointers that point to the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to print a multiplication table that is stored in a 2D array by using pointers to pointers.  When I run this code, it only prints out the "1s" column.  If I remove the outer loop's incrementation and the line break conditional, then it will print the numbers 1-10 ten times.  I don't understand this behavior.

```
printf("\n");
printf("Multiplication Table in standard array syntax\n");

int a[10][10];
int j;
int k;
int prod;
for (j = 1; j < 11; j++){
    for (k = 1; k < 11; k++){
        prod = j*k;
        a[j - 1][k - 1] = prod;
        printf("%d ", a[j - 1][k - 1]);
        if (k == 10)
            printf("\n");
    }
}

printf("\n");
printf("Multiplication Table in standard + pointer syntax\n");

int *pi[10];
int x;
for (x = 0; x <10; x++){
    pi[x] = a[x];
}

int y;
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    for (y = 0; y < 10; y++){
        printf("%d ", *(pi[x] + y));
        if (y == 9)
            printf("\n");
    }
}

printf("\n");
printf("Multpilication Table in pure pointer syntax\n");

int **ppi;
ppi = pi;
int p;
int q;
for (p = 0; p < 10; p++){
    for (q = 0; q < 10; q++){
        printf("%d", *(*ppi + q));
        if (q = 9)
            printf("\n");
    }
    ppi++;
}

}
```

Comment: @Gone What is about that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only typo is `if (q = 9)`

Change it to `if (q == 9)` as that is terminating your loop

Comment: there is not mistake?

Comment: In which question? What line?

Comment: Thanks, I know that's how I'm supposed to set it up, but I make that mistake so often :P

Comment: :) Weekend has something to do with it i guess ;)

Comment: @Gone :D No I am not drunk :P

Answer (score 1):

the first 2 blocks are working fine, in the third block you have `q = 9` instead of `q == 9` (as gregkow said). There is a coding style for if-clauses (called [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)) thas has the value first:

```
if( 9 == q )
```

This would fail on a typo like this:

```
if( 9 = q )
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:51:15: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     if (9 = q)
           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the `if (q = 9)` line. C has no problem with this (it sets `q` equal to 9 and then checks if nonzero). This would likely both end your for loop early and print new lines.